# Will USB (vs ethernet) significantly improve data transfer rate from a SATA disk to a Synology DS223?

Tags: rsync

The firmware upgrade has borked the WD MyCloud.   The MyCloud's drive was removed and examined with Ubuntu's gParted:

[image]

The first option is to rsync through a Gigabit Ethernet connection.  I like rsync because it can be interrupted and pickup from where it left off.  I have this currently running now and it will take several days to transfer.  rsync reports that  large files (1GB) are transferring at ***240 Megabits/S (30 MB/s)
at best:*** well under the Gigabit ethernet limit.   I am left to wonder if switching to [USB will make any difference](https://www.reddit.com/r/synology/comments/lho0h2/what_transfer_speeds_to_be_expected_with_usb_copy/).

The second option is to attach the MyCloud-SATA-Disk to the USB port ([ext4 is supported](https://kb.synology.com/en-af/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/system_externaldevice_devicelist?version=7)). If transfer are 5GB/s, which is 5X 1GB/S.  I would think that I could rsync in this scenario as well?  I am looking for anyone that has tried both methods to confirm that USB is faster and if there are any "lessons learned".  Maybe I have overlooked a better alternative?

***Why would USB improve the the transfer rate, when the observed ethernet transfer rate (30MB/S) is significantly less than a gigabit? (125MB/S)?***

If you have experience performing this exercise, please state this in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The bounding limit for speed across a network transfer is `ssh` and a relatively small packet window. (I can't find the statistics for this at the moment that I thought were somewhere in the stackexchange websites.)

Consequently you may get better throughout avoiding the network altogether. My suggestion would be to consider using `cp -a` for a first pass to a blank target and feeling back to `rsync` if that copy is interrupted for any reason or if you already have files in the destination.

In a network copy you would want to use compression unless you are already CPU bound, and definitely avoid explicit checksums, using times instead:

```
rsync -avzHX /source rHost:/destination
```

In a local to local copy you would want to avoid compression and checksums, relying on times:

```
rsync -avHX /source /destination
```

Replace the flags `-aX` with `-rt` if ownerships and permissions are not to be copied.